# Marking a compute instance as busy to prevent disrupting connections

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Golang service using TCP running on GCP's compute VMs with autoscaling. When the CPU usage spikes, new instances are created and deployed (as expected), but when the CPU usage settles again the instances are destroyed. This would be fine and it's entirely reasonable as to why this is done, but destroying instances does not take into account the established TCP connections and thus disconnects users.

I'd like to keep the VM instances running until the last connection has been closed to prevent disconnecting users. Is there a way to mark the instance as "busy" telling the autoscaler not to remove that instance until it isn't busy? I have implemented health checks but these do not signal the busyness of the instance, only whether the instance is alive or not.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable Connection Draining for your auto-scaling group:

> If the group is part of a backend service that has enabled connection draining, it can take up to 60 seconds after the connection draining duration has elapsed before the VM instance is removed or deleted.
>
> Here are the steps on how to achieve this:
>
> 1. Go to the Load balancing page in the Google Cloud Console.
> 2. Click the Edit button for your load balancer or create a new load balancer.
> 3. Click Backend configuration.
> 4. Click Advanced configurations at the bottom of your backend service.
> 5. In the Connection draining timeout field, enter a value from 0 - 3600. A setting of 0 disables connection draining.

Currently you can request connection draining timeout upto 3600s (= 1hour) which should be suffice for your requirements.

see: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/understanding-autoscaler-decisions

Comment: This is definitely makes the situation better, but sometimes the connection could last for several hours. While this is unlikely and increasing the draining timeout does help, it doesn't completely fix my issue. Is there no way of marking the instance as busy until further notice?

Comment: It also looks like with a TCP load balancer connection draining timeouts cannot be set as the "Advanced configurations" section does not exist in the load balancing edit page.

Comment: If you make the instance busy then scale down event won't happen and more and more requests will get routed to your instance which is pending scale down. I can't think of a clean way of doing this. Any chance you can explain why your connection can last hours? Maybe you can internally save work while the instance is scaling down and dynamically route the request behind the scenes. I'll have think if you can provide more context.

Comment: I have a scalable gateway deployed to GCP that does some simple authentication checks and proxies the connection (if authenticated) to a central TCP service outside of GCP. This service is used by users with a connection time ranging from 30 minutes to a few hours. I have no control of the client software (only the connection host and port) nor do I have much control of the central TCP service. Optimally, I'd like that the LB would ask my gateway if there are any active connections and not destroying if there are any. At the same time, the gateway would stop accepting new connections.

Comment: Also, to be clear: there is no connection draining option available for TCP load balancers; you can only use them with HTTP(S) and internal load balancers, so it's not possible to take advantage of connection draining in my situation.

Comment: That's a tough one, the best way to fix it is either upstream or downstream. Upstream fix: set keep alive to 1h, then the client has to reestablish the connection. Downstream fix: use something like CloudIAP in-front of TCP service, see: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-on-prem-howto. I know they are not quick fixes but that's all I could think of given your scenario.

Comment: Once more thing you can try is to store the session information in an in-memory cache which should make your compute instance stateless. e.g. for tomcat you can use: https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager. I have used this and it works quite well, users retain their login session through scale down events.